# Can I sanitize user input in Aws AppSync resolver mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I let my users to write comments. Someone might write a malicious post maybe containing some scripts.

Can I sanitize user input before saving it to the database or should this request be behind a Lambda that does the sanitization ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html.

You can use VTL code in your mapping template to execute sanitation you require.